# preg_match asterisk

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following code:

```
preg_match('/^\bcount\(\b(?P<name>\w+)\) AS (?P<newName>\w+)$/', $attr, $matches);
```

At this moment it only accepts strings if they are of the form "count(*someword*) AS *someword*". But I want that it also accepts the string if it says: `count(*) AS bla`

I tried `(\w+|\*)`, but this didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closed, remove the `\b`:

```
preg_match('/^\bcount\((?P<name>\w+|\*)\) AS (?P<newName>\w+)$/', $attr, $matches);
```